# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider' on bootstrap=slider plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Having a slight issue with the bootstrap-slider plugin from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/.

Getting this error:  Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'

From the following code:

```
<head>
<link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./bootstrap/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./bootstrap/css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="test/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="test/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider-price').slider();
});
</script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<div class="col-md-6">
   <span class="logo-font-sb-md">Price: £1<input id="slider-price" class="logo-font-el-sm" value="" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[250,450]"/> <b>€ 1000</b>
</div>
```

I'm quite new to jQuery so i have most likely made a stupid error but would appreciate a poke in the correct direction!

Further clarification:

It is not a 404 error with the js files, or a loading sequence order.

Comment: I would guess that bootstrap needs to be included before the bootstrap plugin as it probably extends the bootstrap object when it is included. Change the order of the two bootstrap JS includes.

Answer (score 0):

try to invert the order of bootstrap and bootstrap slider:

```
<script type="test/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<script type="test/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="test/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="test/javascript" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
```

Comment: Afraid not, the only reason they are the wrong way round in the opening sample is that i moved them to see if there was some strange sequencing going on in the plugin so i've moved them back to your suggested (and my original) order.

Answer (score 0):

Use `../` not `./` to locate parent folder. Also, reverse the inclusion order of `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap-slider.js`

## HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its located in a subfolder because of a holding page so i don't want it to go directly to the root because it isn't there. Its not a 404 on either of those files they are present where it is looking.